# Next Js folder structure for redirecting to thank you page on hitting an API from different pages

Tags: next.js, routes, directory-structure

I'm new in Nextjs and I have created pages such as pageA, pageB, pageC and a folder containing pageX, pageY and pageZ in pages folder.
All these pages have a form where on successful API response I want to redirect to a thank you page and the url should be like:

localhost:3000/pageA/thankYou
localhost:3000/pageB/thankYou
localhost:3000/folder/pageX/thankYou
localhost:3000/folder/pageY/thankYou

currently I am able to achieve it by creating the thankYou page like [...thankYou].js in the pages folder but because of this whenever I hit wrong URL it redirects to thankYou page instead of 404 page in local and in dev it redirects to homepage with incorrect URL intact.

P.S: I have created a static website and I'm using next export. 
Can anyone guide me a way to achieve the required routing?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making a single thankyou page in the `/pages` directory, and then having the forms redirect to that page, if the thank you needs to have specific data, you could pass it as a url or query parameter like so:

```
import Router from "next/router"

<form>
    <button onClick={() => {

        // form logic
 
        // page redirect
        Router.push("/thankyou?page=pageX");
    }} />
</form>
```

Comment: I have already created a single thankyou page in the /pages folder and also redirecting to it using router.push